# "Variable declaratorid expected after this method" error in java class file

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm looking for help on an error that I am getting while trying to create this java class. I want to add test scores as well as the average for this student class. I have tried a lot of things and I cant seem to get the error *"Variable declaratorid expected after this method"* to go away when I reach my setTestScore method shown below (shown with arrows) similarly in my next getTestScore method I have an error *"cant invoke getTest() on the primitive type int."* (also show with arrows)

```
 public class Student {

private String firstName, lastName;
private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress;
private int TestScore, testScores ;
private int testScore1, testScore2, testScore3;;

public void TestScore(int testScore1, int testScore2, int testScore3)
{
    this.testScore1 = testScore1;
    this.testScore2 = testScore2;
    this.testScore3 = testScore3;   

}

public Student(String first, String last, Address home, Address school)
{
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.homeAddress = home;
    this.schoolAddress = school;


}

testScores = new TestScore(testScore1, testScore2, testScore3);

public void setTestScore(int testNumber, int TestScore) {
    if(testNumber==1) {
        testScores.setTest1(>>testScore<<);
    }
    else if(testNumber==2) {
        testScores.setTest2(>>testScore<<);
    }
    else if(testNumber==3) {
        testScores.setTest3(>>testScore<<);
    }
}
public void setTest1(int test1) {
    this.testScore1 = test1;
}
public void setTest2(int test2) {
    this.testScore2 = test2;
}
public void setTest3(int test3) {
    this.testScore3 = test3;
}


public int getTestScore(int testNumber) {

    if(testNumber==1) {
        return >>testScores.getTest1<<();
    }
    else if(testNumber==2) {
        return >>testScores.getTest2<<();
    }
    else if(testNumber==3) {
        return >>testScores.getTest3<<();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
public int getTest1() {
    return testScore1;
}
public int getTest2() {
    return testScore2;
}
public int getTest3() {
    return testScore3;
}   

public double getAverageTestScores() {
    double avg;

    avg=(testScores.getTest1() + testScores.getTest2() + testScores.getTest3())/3.0;

    return avg;
}

public String toString()
{
    String result;

    result = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    result += "Home Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
    result += "School Address:\n" + schoolAddress + "\n";
    result +="Test Score 1:\n" + testScores.getTest1() + "\n";
    result +="Test Score 2:\n" + testScores.getTest2() + "\n";
    result +="TestScore 3:\n" + testScores.getTest3() + "\n";
    result +="Average test score:\n" + getAverageTestScores() + "\n";
    return result;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this statement

```
testScores = new TestScore(testScore1, testScore2, testScore3);
```

and where ever you have used

```
testScores.foo
```

in your program,replace it with

```
this.foo
```

Comment: still gives the same error but only instead of underlining only the testScore it underlines the whole line testScores.setTest1(TestScore)

Comment: @BriTheCyberGuy18 hi, i have edited my response as you question is more clearer now based on the comments below. please check as this should work.

Answer (score 0):

remove this statement

```
testScores = new TestScore(testScore1, testScore2, testScore3);
```

and where ever you have used

```
testScores.foo
```

in your program,replace it with

```
this.foo
```

Comment: I mean: private TestScore testScores ;

Comment: So that fixed one thing but now private TestScore has an error “can’t be resolved to a type” and the testscore every where else can’t be resolved as a type either. I’m really stumped. I know it’s probably something simple but I can’t figure it out

Comment: U don't have class named "TestScore" so you can't create type of this class. Create new class in project named "TestScore",

Comment: that was my original plan that fixed everything but the problem for school that I'm trying to follow wants me to make it apart of the student class

Comment: @XeWion sorry i accidentally placed and edit request on your answer instead of editing mine. you can feel free to disregard it !